# Will Google go by my sitemap.xml or also include it's own crawled URLs

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a website which has recently employed "friendly IDs" like the following:

```
/users/bob-barker
```

I have created a very explicit sitemap.xml which includes the friendly URLs like the one above, but for some reason the Google search results for my site are still showing up like:

```
/users/143
```

There are still some links on my site like the above, so do I need to change them all to the friendly style to ensure Google is not aware of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a 301 redirect from the old URLs to the new URLs. This tells Google the URLs have changed and where to find them. It also makes sure that all of the SEO value these URLs have earned (i.e. links, PageRank) also get associated with the new URLs.

After doing this it will take some time for Google to update its index accordingly. That amount of time varies so I can't give you an estimate. But it usually takes weeks to happen so don't be surprised if ti takes a while to occur.